# Initialization of Object not possible

Tags: ios, swift, object, initialization

I am trying to set up a simple User object in my app, when I try to initialize the object or access it's parameters I'm not able to do so, it usually throws the following error:

> Argument passed to call that takes no parameters

This feels like a beginner's issue but I have no idea why it's happening.

Here's the code I use for the object:

```
import Foundation
import Firebase

class User {

  var username: String
  var image: String
  var email: String

  init(username: String, image: String, email: String) {
       self.username = username
       self.image = image
       self.email = email
  }

   func toAny() -> [String: Any] {
      return ["username": username, "image": image, "email": email]
   }
}
```

and then I imagine I should be able to do:

```
let user = User(username: "usr", image: "img", email: "mail")
```

but that doesn't work, it throws the error mentioned above

So I tried instantiating the object in the scope like:

```
let user: User?
```

and then

```
user.username = "usr"
```

but that didn't work either...

I have been working with Swift apps for over 2 years and I still have issues with the simplest of things sometimes, but since I can't find any great references online I thought I'd try my luck here. Though I agree it's a silly question I would love an explanation of what I'm doing wrong and how to never encounter this issue again.

[image]

Comment: It looks like there is another User somewhere in available namespaces. Try to rename *your* User somehow differently, like MyUser... just to check.

Comment: @Asperi That is most likely the issue since Firebase is imported and it has a User class

Comment: @Asperi that was the issue, nice catch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's due to the ambiguity between `User` created by you and the `User` class in the `FirebaseAuth Framework`

Try renaming your `User` class to something more specific to your use-case. Accessing its variables should not cause any issue.